# Django: saving data from user input and display

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a jwysiwyg editor. Looking at it, it can use basic-formatting html tags using the formatting buttons like SO's. Upon submitting the form, I notice its saved into the database as-is, whereas if I enter stuff like `<iframe> ... </iframe>` into the editor I notice that it is html-encoded inside the table.

Now, when I need to output whatever the user has submitted, can I safely use `{{ output|safe }}` to display the formatted text?

Is this reasonably secure enough or how should I rectify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `safe` filter only if you html-escape the data first. Otherwise you should use `escape`. If you want your users to be able to input data with html tags you could try to sanitize the input to prevent users from using `<iframe>`, `<script>`, etc, but allow other tags to be white-listed, and then mark it as `safe`.

Comment: assuming that my wysiwyg editor on the client side already handles the unsafe tags before sending to the server, can i safely assume using |safe is alright?

Comment: If you trust it, then yes. You can also use [django.utils.safestring.mark_safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) to mark a string as safe.